# Вставка символов Javascript

Tags: javascript

Имеется строка в которой известны координаты символа **X**. Каким образом можно подставить **пробелы** после каждого символа **X** в этой строке?

Comment: что за координаты имееются ввиду?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну и зачем Вам координаты? Просто сделайте замену `Х` -> `X`

```js
var str = 'aXbXcXd';
var newStr = str.replace(/X/g, 'X ');
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Видимо, имелась в виду замена `str[X] -> str[X]+' '`

Answer (score 0):

Поможет динамическое создание регулярного выражения:

```js
function spacify(str, i) {
  if (!str[i]) return str;
  return str.replace(new RegExp(str[i], 'g'), str[i] + ' ');
}
console.log(spacify('abba', 0)); // 'a bba '
console.log(spacify('abba', 1)); // 'ab b a'
```